# django channel_layer.send not sync even use async_to_sync

Tags: django, django-channels

```
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    
    def connect(self):
        print(self.channel_name)
        self.accept()
    
    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass
    
    def receive(self, text_data):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.send)(self.channel_name, {
            "type": "chat.message",
            "text": "1",
        })
        print("=============channel================")
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.send)(self.channel_name, {
            "type": "chat.message",
            "text": "2",
        })
    
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event["text"]
        print(message)
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'message': message}))
```

i call `channel_layer.send` twice in receive function , suppose should print like

```
1

========channel========

2
```

but it print

```
=========channel=======

1

2
```

anyone could help to tell me where have problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `channel` like a Queue. On receiving any data from client, your `receive` function is triggered. **`async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.send)`** only send the message to the `Queue(channel)`, waiting for correct handler(`chat_message`) to consume it. When the `receive` function is finished, the `chat_message` then is triggered to print received messages

```
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    ...
    
    def receive(self, text_data):
        # -> sending to channel, not consumed by `chat_message` yet
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.send)(self.channel_name, {
            "type": "chat.message",
            "text": "1",
        })  
        # -> print
        print("=============channel================")  
        # -> sending to channel, not consumed by `chat_message` yet
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.send)(self.channel_name, {
            "type": "chat.message",
            "text": "2",
        })
    
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event["text"]
        # print the received messages 
        print(message)
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'message': message}))
```

#### Async

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    ...
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        # give control back to the loop, `chat_message` is triggerd
        await self.channel_layer.send(self.channel_name, {
            "type": "chat.message",
            "text": "1",
        })
        print("=============channel================")
        await self.channel_layer.send(self.channel_name, {
            "type": "chat.message",
            "text": "2",
        })
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but if i want to send the message immediately not wait for receive fucntion finish.. because i may call channel_layer.send multiple time ...like a log .. 
  what should i do ?

Comment: @JasonCheng  this could be achieved easily using `async` code, `await` will give control back to event loop by default.